# Pass parameters to a method which is expected to throw an error?

Tags: javascript, testing, qunit

First steps with QUnit. Apologies if this is hyper-simple. I'm trying to understand things from [this page](https://api.qunitjs.com/assert/throws) of the manual.

If I have this:

```
QUnit.test( 'test init throws', function( assert ){
    assert.throws( loader.init, 'some message' )
});
```

... is there any way to pass parameters to that call to function `init( param1, param2 )`?

Comment: Not totally sure if this would work, but could you maybe use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for this, by doing `loader.init.bind(this,arg1,arg2,...)`

Comment: Clever, thank you! in my case it is then `loader.init.bind( loader, arg1, arg2 ...)` ... but it works! Care to make it an answer? Recognition is due.

Comment: Great! Thank you! I'll turn into an answer—may be good to wait to see if there are any more formally documented solutions for it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript's [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) functionality for this, which will return a function with the parameters bound to it, by doing something of the form (where here we'd be passing in `arg1` and `arg2`):

```js
QUnit.test('test init throws', function(assert){
    assert.throws(loader.init.bind(loader, arg1, arg2), 'some message')
});
```

Comment: Not only does this work, but I'm also finding that (parameterless) `assert.throws` is **not** working unless you use this solution. With the non-`bind` usage (as per manual) I get false positives: tests passing as though an error thrown, when this was not the case. Puzzling.